# How would I be able to create a function Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, format

I want to add a piece of code to the already existing code that checks if the `High` column values are greater than of the other values of the rows for the columns `Open, Low, Close`. I also want to do a checkup to see if the `Low` columns row values are lower than of the other columns `Open, High, Close` columns rows values. So in row 1 of The value for the `High` column does not meet this criteria as the `Open and Close` values are higher than it so it is in the expected output. So essentially this code is supposed to checkup if each of `High` value remains to be the greatest value and the `Low` value is the lowest for each row.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import datetime

A =[[1645661520000, 37352.0, 37276.5, 37252.0, 37376.0, 15.56119087], 
[1645661580000, 37376.0, 37414.0, 37376.0, 37314.0, 49.38248589], 
[1645661640000, 37414.0, 37414.0, 37350.0, 37350.0, 45.70306699], 
[1645661700000, 37350.0, 37374.0, 37350.0, 37373.5, 14.4306948], 
[1645661760000, 37373.5, 36588.0, 37373.5, 37388.0, 3.59340947], 
[1645661820000, 37388.0, 37388.0, 37388.0, 39388.0, 21.45525727]]

column_names = ["Unix","Open", "High","Low", "Close", "Volume"]
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=column_names)
df.insert(1,"Date", pd.to_datetime(df["Unix"].to_numpy()/1000,unit='s'))
display(df)
```

[image]

Expected Output:

```
Rows: 1, 5, 6
#Row 1 is low column is the highest of all than all the other rows 
#Row 5 the High column is lower than the other columns 
#Row 6 the low column  is higher than the other columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# columns of interest
val_cols = ['Open', 'High', 'Low',  'Close']

# This is where High condition is violated
high_cond_violated = df['High'] < df[val_cols].max(axis=1)

# This is where Low condition is violated
low_cond_violated = df['Low'] > df[val_cols].min(axis=1)

# These are the indices where either condition is violated
(df.index[high_cond_violated | low_cond_violated] + 1).values.tolist()
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

You can call them separately to see which one is actually violated eg

```
# Only High condition violated
(df.index[high_cond_violated] + 1).values.tolist()
...
```